# Regular Expression: Changes HTML Attributes Value to some pattern

Tags: html, regex, netbeans

I have thousands html tags, have wrote like this: 
 
`<input type="text" name="CustomerName" />` 
`<input type="text" name="SalesOrder"/>`

I need to match every `name` attribute values and convert them all to be like this:
`CustomerName -> cust[customer_name]`
`SalesOrder -> cust[sales_order]`

So the results will be :
 
`<input type="text" name="cust[customer_name]" />` 
`<input type="text" name="cust[sales_order]" />`

My best try have stuck in this pattern:
`name=\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\"`
 -> just found `name="CustomerName"`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$subject = <<<EOT
<input type="text" name="CustomerName" />
<input type="text" name="SalesOrder"/>
EOT;
$pattern = '/\\bname=["\']([A-Za-z0-9]+)["\']/';
$output = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($match) {
    return ''
    . 'name="cust['
    . strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])/', '_$1', $match[1]))
    . ']"';
}, $subject);
?>
<pre><?php echo htmlentities($output);?></pre>
```

Output looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="cust[customer_name]" />
<input type="text" name="cust[sales_order]"/>
```

Comment: Dear kristof, what a smart technique. You was done this like magics ! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Brain, could you be so kind as to click on the big V next to my answer? That way I get points. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML is not a good use of RegEx. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

With that said, this might be a small enough task that it won't drive you insane.
You'd need something like:

Find: `name="(.+)"`

Replace: `name="cust[$1]"`

and then hope that your HTML isn't very irregular (most is, but you can always hope).

Update: here's some [`sed`-fu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2038/convert-camelcase-to-underscores-camel_case) to get you started on camelCase -> underscores.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response 
i'm playing around the camelCase now